# Ternary operator inside calculation PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to set an array with the sum of values contained in an object. However, when one of the properties ("shares" in this example) is not set in the object, the operation should continue without throwing the following error:

" [ErrorException] Undefined property: stdClass::$shares "

I am trying unsuccessfully to a ternary operator to achieve this, as shown below:

```
$array = [strtotime('today midnight') =>
           $ExternalPost->reactions->summary->total_count ?: 0 +
           $ExternalPost->comments->summary->total_count ?: 0 +
           ($ExternalPost->shares->count ? $ExternalPost->shares->count : 0)
         ];
```

It looks like the operator is evaluating everything, including the other two preceding objects/value. How can I constrain the evaluated value to be only the last  one "$ExternalPost->shares->count" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend rewriting your logic so it doesn't use multiple ternary operators together. The PHP [comparison operators documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) says:

> **Note:**
>
> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:
>
> **Example #4 Non-obvious Ternary Behaviour**
>
> ```
> <?php
> // on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
> echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');
>
> // however, the actual output of the above is 't'
> // this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right
>
> // the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
> echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');
>
> // here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
> // in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
> // second ternary expression.
> ?>
> ```

This is because PHP's ternary operator is left-associative instead of right-associative, like it is in most other languages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason the operation should continue without that error if `$ExternalPost->shares` is undefined.   This needs to be defined if you're checking for `$ExternalPost->shares->count`

Else, you can change the logic to something like:

```
((isset($ExternalPost->shares) && $ExternalPost->shares->count) ? $ExternalPost->shares->count : 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will throw an error if you attempt to access an object property or array key that does not exists, even if you're only doing so to check if it exists. Instead, you should use [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/property-exists) (for objects), or [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array-key-exists) (for arrays), or [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) (for anything). Using one of those methods allows you to check whether a variable/property/key exists without throwing an error if it doesn't.

Your example could be rewritten as:

```
...
(isset($ExternalPost->shares->count) ? $ExternalPost->shares->count : 0)
```

Comment: If `$ExternalPost->shares->count` is `NULL`, then `isset(...)` will return `FALSE`, which causes the ternary operator to return the latter `0`. This matches the result of the original code. Unless I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code amounts to

```
if ($ExternalPost->reactions->summary->total_count) {
    $a = $ExternalPost->reactions->summary->total_count;
} else {
    if ($ExternalPost->comments->summary->total_count) {
      $a = 0 + $ExternalPost->comments->summary->total_count;
    } elseif($ExternalPost->shares->count) {
      $a = 0 + $ExternalPost->shares->count
    } else {
      $a = 0;
    }
}
```

Example http://ideone.com/c9bY5o

---

The ternary conditions should have wrapping parentheses and validation of the properties, in order to differentiate the existing values and retrieved values.

```
(isset($ExternalPost->reactions->summary->total_count) ? $ExternalPost->reactions->summary->total_count : 0) +
(isset($ExternalPost->comments->summary->total_count) ? $ExternalPost->comments->summary->total_count : 0) +
(isset($ExternalPost->shares->count) ? $ExternalPost->shares->count : 0);
```

Otherwise use verbose format, which is a lot easier to read.

```
if (isset($ExternalPost->reactions->summary->total_count)) {
    $a = $ExternalPost->reactions->summary->total_count;
} else {
    $a = 0;
}
if (isset($ExternalPost->comments->summary->total_count)) {
    $a += $ExternalPost->comments->summary->total_count;
} else {
    $a += 0;
}
if (isset($ExternalPost->shares->count)) {
    $a += $ExternalPost->shares->count;
} else {
    $a += 0;
}
```

Example http://ideone.com/GKkpZw

*Note that the object has had `reactions` and `shares` properties removed.*

---

As for a recommendation, I suggest instead you assign methods to the objects and get the totals that way. So you only need to maintain the calculations in one location and have the ability to reuse it in other scripts.

That way if you want to do something more sophisticated with the data, need to display it elsewhere, or you decide to change or add on to the object(s) or calculation(s) later, it will be much easier. For example only total the reactions and comments when the post has shares, or adding Up and Down Votes.

Rough Lazy Getter OOP Example - it can be refactored to tally up the totals on setting of the values instead, accept an array of values, etc.

```
class ExternalPost
{
    private $reactions;

    private $comments;

    private $shares;

    public function __construct(Reactions $reactions = null, Comments $comments = null, Shares $shares = null) 
    {
        $this->reactions = $reactions;
        $this->comments = $comments;
        $this->shares = $shares;
    }

    public function getReactions()
    {
        if (null === $this->reactions) {
            $this->reactions = new Reactions;
        }
        return $this->reactions;
    }

    public function getComments()
    {
        if (null === $this->comments) {
            $this->comments = new Comments;
        }
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function getShares()
    {
        if (null === $this->shares) {
            $this->shares = new Shares;
        }
        return $this->shares;
    }

    public function getTotal() 
    {
        return $this->getReactions()->getTotal() + 
            $this->getComments()->getTotal() + 
            $this->getShares()->getCount();
    }
}
```

```
class Summary 
{
    private $total_count = 0;

    public function getTotalCount() 
    {
        return $this->total_count;
    }

    public function setTotalCount($total)
    {
        $this->total_count = $total;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
abstract class Summation 
{
    protected $summary;

    public function __construct(Summary $summary = null) 
    {
        $this->summary = $summary;
    }

    public function getSummary()
    {
        if (null === $this->summary) {
            $this->summary = new Summary;
        }

        return $this->summary;
    }

    public function getTotal() 
    {
        return $this->getSummary()->getTotalCount();
    }

    public function setTotal($total)
    {
        $this->getSummary()->setTotalCount($total);

        return $this;
    }
}

class Reactions extends Summation{}

class Comments extends Summation{}
```

```
class Shares 
{
    private $count = 0;

    public function getCount() 
    {
        return $this->count;
    }

    public function setCount($count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So now the code in your Script would look like

```
$reactions = new Reactions;
$reactions->setTotal(1);
$comments = null; 
/*
 $comments = new Comments;
 $comments->setTotal(2);
 //alternative to using getComments below
*/

$ExternalPost = new ExternalPost($reactions, $comments);
/* $ExternalPost->getReactions()->setTotal(1);
   //alternative to defining $reactions above */
$ExternalPost->getComments()->getSummary()->setTotalCount(2);
$ExternalPost->getShares()->setCount(3);

$array = [strtotime('today midnight') => $ExternalPost->getTotal()];
```

Example http://ideone.com/oqSYNd

You could also apply `__set` and `__get` magic methods in order to retain your current code format, but it is highly discouraged as it makes your code a lot less easy to follow.